# iOS: Large files are not immediately opened when using "Open in"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

My app has registered a document handler to open certain files from other apps using the `"Open in"` feature (for instance from Safari or Dropbox).

This works without problems until files are getting larger than `~300 MB`. For files greater than this size the file is copied to my apps `"Inbox"` folder but the app is not brought to foreground but instead I just see the iPhone desktop and the calling app is sent to background. My app is not killed, it is just not brought to foreground. This happens in all situations, e.g. it does not matter if my app is already running or has to be started.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Regards,

Comment: How much free space is available on your device?

Comment: There is enough space (some GB). The file gets correctly copied but the app does remain in background.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are getting a low memory notification and not handling it correctly?

I would look into your 
    -applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:
functions to see if perhaps you are running out of memory.

Comment: No memory warning is triggered. The app just keeps in background and I have to manually bring it to foreground. The file is then correctly available in the "Inbox" folder of my app.